# Showing the radius of convergence for a power series is equal to the radius of convergence for its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Consider the power series:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x - c)^n
$$

Now consider its derivative:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_n (x - c)^{n-1}
$$

We can say at first that the Radius of Convergence for the original power series is

$$
R = \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_{n+1} / a_{n}|
$$

(via the Ratio Test).

On the other hand, **can we not also say that** the radius of convergence for the derivative of the power series is

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{(n+1) a_{n+1}}{n a_{n}} \right| = |a_{n+1} / a_{n}| = R?
$$

via the same argument?  Is my reasoning correct?  That is, is the argument that the Radius of Convergence the same for both a power series and its derivative really this simple? :)

Comment: I changed the title.

Comment: The radius of convergence is not always given by the ratio test. When the ratio test does give it, however, your argument works.

Comment: @zhw: Do you mean that the ratio test only gives the radius of convergence AFTER you have shown that the power series does indeed converge?

Comment: No, I'm saying what I wrote. For example  $x + x^2/2^2 + x^3 + x^4/2^4 + x^5 + x^6/2^6 + \cdots $ has radius of convergence 1, but the ratio test fails miserably here.

Answer (score 11):

Observe that

$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|na_n|}$$

since $\;\sqrt[n]n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$ , so both power series convergence radius are the same.

Comment: What if this limsup equals $1$? By the root test, this may be inconclusive.

Comment: @user1770201 You seem to have missed the point. Google "Cauchy-Hadamard formula" or something like that: it *gives you* the radius of convergence $\;R\;$  by means of the formula $$R=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$  and thus what my answer proves is that both a power series *and its derivative* power series have the same radius of convergnece.

Comment: @DonAntonio I was looking for a proof of the fact that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^\frac{1}{n} = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |na_n|^\frac{1}{n} $. What is the standard way of doing it?

Comment: @Anu you could use, I guess, that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1\ldots$$

Comment: Wouldn't the terms in the derivative series be shifted? How would we show that $$\limsup_{a_n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \limsup_{a_n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n-1}}?$$

Comment: @F.Tomas$$|a_n|^{\frac1{n-1}}=\left(|a_n|^{1/n}\right)^{\frac n{n-1}}$$

Comment: @DonAntonio, even if $|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n-1}}=(|a_n|^{1/n})^{\frac{n}{n-1}}$ how if follows that $\limsup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$? I am bit confused.

Comment: @ZFR Lim sup of $\;|a_n|^{1/n}\;$ is the usual way to calculate the convergence radius (its reciprocal, in fact), and $\;\frac n{n-1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, Please sorry but I still did not get your point. Could you give some details, please?

Comment: Since  $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac1R$$ then also $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\right)^{\frac n{n-1}}=\frac1R$$ You could use here the squeeze theorem, in case the limit is finite. And if the limit is infinite then it will be infinite in the other case as well.

Comment: @user1770201 There's nothing inconclusive about that. It just means $R=1.$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nx^n$ is $R.$ Then $\sum a_nx^n$ converges absolutely for $x\in (-R,R).$ Now fix an $x_0 \in (-R,R),$ and choose $y\in (-R,R)$ with $|y| > |x_0|.$ Then $n|a_nx_0^n| = |a_ny^n|n|x_0/y|^n.$ Because $|x_0/y| < 1,$ $n|x_0/y|^n \to 0.$ Since $\sum |a_ny^n| < \infty,$ $\sum |na_nx_0^n| < \infty.$ It follows that the radius of convergence of $\sum na_nx^n$ is at least $R.$

Comment: This is wrong. The coefficients of x^n is not na_n

Comment: @JohnMitchell  I don't understand your comment. I showed that for each $x_0\in (-R,R),$ the series $\sum na_nx_0^n$ converges absolutely. This implies the ROC of $\sum na_nx^n$ is at least $R.$

Comment: No what you've shown is that $\sum na_nx^n$ converges. We've to show $\sum (n+1)a_(n+1)x^n$ converges

Comment: @JohnMitchell That follows trivially from what I showed.

Comment: Why do you pause here? Are there examples where the derivative $f'$ of a power series $f$ has a larger convergence disc than $f$?